# Sykpe For Business message sending through Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, skypedeveloper, skype4py

how should i use in python3 to connect to Sky for Business and send some messages to user over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Official [Skype Developer website](https://dev.skype.com/) can give you the features it supports. But unfortunately the one you need is not there.

[Skype4Py](https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py) should do the trick. Its not an official library.
Based on the docs:

```
from Skype4Py import Skype
import sys

client = Skype()
client.Attach()
user = sys.argv[1]
message = ' '.join(sys.argv[2:]
client.SendMessage(user, message)
```

This snippet should ideally help you out.

[**Update:** Library compatibility with python 3.x is still a question. Alternatively you can also check **[Skpy](https://skpy.t.allofti.me/)** which also supports python 3.x]

Hope it helped.

Comment: thanks will check this

Comment: Does it only support Skype or Skype for Business as well?